# How to change Value in listbox of specific item or row?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am working in Visual c++. I added Some rows in listbox using loop,now i want Change Specific line in listbox.
Example,

```
listbox->items(linenumber)->value= "changed value";
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way can be,

```
listbox->DeleteString(linenumber);
listbox->InsertString(linenumber, _T("changed value"));
```